# Google Search Console says "Video is not the main content of the page". But it IS

Tags: google-search-console, video

My website has a section dedicated to videos.  When the user follows the link for a specific video, they are taken to a page just for that video.  Other than 3 sentences describing the video, a contact form at the bottom where the visitor can connect with us with respect to that particular video, and a sidebar of related links, the Video is the only other thing on the page - it is the centerpiece of the page.

Why is google deindexing this as a video result?

The page:  https:// www. aoccorp. com / services / risk-based-inspection

[image: hard to argue that the video is not the main content of this page]

Any ideas?  Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me, on a mobile, I have to scroll down quite a bit to see your video.

Google is currently very strict about its "main content" restriction. People who have a video fill the initial screen are still struggling to get the video indexed.

Hopefully their algorithm for deciding this will get more balanced in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Tony.  I added a screenshot - it's hard to argue the video isn't the main content.  I get your point about mobile.  Admittedly, the website is a little dated.  Sadly, our customers are pretty firmly entrenched in desktop environments.  So, yes, hopefully they make some adjustments.

Comment: And, oddly enough (or maybe not), the majority of our video pages - which have the exact same format - are indexed video pages with no issues at all.  Oh well.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google uses the mobile version of a page. In their case, it may be that most visitors are desktop-based, however, Google will still focus on the mobile version for analysis and indexing.